# How do I keep a centered background image from breaking the layout?

Tags: css

http://www.goodshow.tv

I'm having issues with the background image.  The layout looks right if the browser is wide enough, but when you make it too narrow, the background keeps moving off to the left.  Is there a way to keep it from moving?

Comment: Which browser are you using?  It looks fine to me in Chrome?

Comment: FYI all: this occurs in firefox, not ie7 or chrome

Comment: Ah.. IE 8 looks wrong...

Comment: It doesn't happen in safari either, weird.  You can see the problem in Firefox and IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is happening when the page width gets less than that of the `<div id="body">` div, causing that div to no longer be centered. I found that I was able to solve this on Firefox at least by adding:

```
html { min-width: 980px }
```

Comment: Terrific!  Thanks Tobias!  "I've been in the film business for a while but I just cant seem to get one in the can." ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the white portion from the background image, and make the left sidebar background white with CSS's background rule. Add the image to the right portion only. Maintain the width of the left sidebar.

Comment: the problem with coloring just the nav bar etc. is that I want the white to extend to the left edge and bottom edge no matter how wide/tall the browser is.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is related to using both body and #body css selectors (one for the tag called `body` and one for the div named `body`

Is the intent that the nav area has a white background and the #content div has the image background?

Could you try this instead of what you have?:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
    float: right;
    width: 720px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, but probably a good idea to change it and avoid confusion!  Thanks!

Comment: See my comment on apphacker's answer, same applies to the dark BG.

Comment: Ya, I tried it with firebug, and it fixed the float issue, but only applied the background to that div...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just encapsulate the entire left side with a white background div?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that both the nav and content areas are floating, and the content has an absolute width.

Quickest fix is the set the background-color on #nav to white. This will still cause issues for the header (Good Show, and A creative studio in Atlanta) but I think you need to revisit how you are doing that portion anyway (they are just 2 images)

Probably better to have 2 columns all the way to the top and those images can be in a fixed-height div in the top of each